# Can I create a CKRecordZone on the fly in the production environment of CloudKit

Tags: ios, cloudkit, dev-to-production, ckrecordzone

I am creating a CKRecordZone on the fly in code, which of course works in development on CloudKit.

But will it work in production? Can I create CKRecordZones in production on the fly? Or do I need to rethink the design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create zones in a user's private database on the fly in production.

Just make sure you deploy the scheme to production when ready. Please see the [Deploying the Schema](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/DeployingYourCloudKitApp/DeployingYourCloudKitApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH10-SW2) chapter in the [CloudKit Quick Start](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987)

Also be sure you test your app using Test Flight using the production database before submitting your app to the App Store.